# Magento foreign key constrain... do I need to commit transaction first?

Tags: magento-1.9

Please have a look at my function which deletes certain products and attributes.

If I recreate the same attributes in the same function, I get this foreign key constrain error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a 
child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nova-
computers`.`catalog_product_entity_int`
```

I think I need to commit the delete transaction, but i'm not sure what code 
im missing.

```
public function reset_attr_products($productcode, $icecat_category)
{
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);

    #####################################################
    #############  PRODUCTS #############################
    #####################################################
    $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
    try {
        $connection->beginTransaction();

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $productcode);
        if ($product) {
            $product->delete();
        }
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->save();

        $connection->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $connection->rollback();
    }

    #####################################################
    #############  Attributes ###########################
    #####################################################
    $attributecode_starting = $icecat_category."_";

    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
        ->getItems();

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attributecode = $attribute->getAttributecode();

        if (strpos($attributecode, $attributecode_starting) === 0) {
            $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
            try {
                $connection->beginTransaction();

                $model = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');  
                $model->startSetup();
                // Make saves and other actions that affect the database
                $model->removeAttribute('catalog_product', $attributecode);
                $model->endSetup();

                $connection->commit();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $connection->rollback();
            }
        }
    }

    Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
}
```

Comment: Can you plese explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to clear the attributes and the products for a certain product group. After that i want to programmatically add the products again. This will fix any problems with the current product data and attributes in magento. The thing is, if I run the functions seperetly, so that means I have to run two instances of chrome, no problems occur.

Comment: You can disable foreign key check at product insert time. After the products insertions you can enable this.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that. Does the problem still exist?

Answer (score 0):

For deleting products by SKU and attributes by attribute code this should be enough ...

```
public function reset_attr_products($productcode, $icecat_category)
{
    # product
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $productcode);
    if ($product) {
        $product->delete();
    }

    # attributes
    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('like' => $icecat_category . '_%'));

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attribute->delete();
    }
}
```